# Is there a way in pygame to find collisions within a group

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

The pygame module utilizes groups in a variety of its collision detection methods.

I have been trying to find a way to find collisions for a sprite against other members that are contained in the same group.

In the example -

```py
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(creature, creaturegroup, False)
```

this continues to provide a false positive for collision detection, which I believe is due to the 'creature' sprite being contained within the 'creaturegroup' group. Any suggested workarounds for finding collisions within a group?

Comment: yes, the suggestions from the previous responder were successful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a temporary *Group* that contains all of the *Sprites* but the one you want to test:

```py
test_group = pagame.sprite.Group([s for s in creaturegroup if s != creature])
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(creature, test_group, False)
```

---

Another option is to write your own test function, that skips equal objects:
(See [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect))

```py
def collide_if_not_self(left, right):
    if left != right:
        return pygame.sprite.collide_rect(left, right)
    return False
```

```py
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(creature, creaturegroup, False, collide_if_not_self)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both of these suggestions and they have each worked as a solution in my project!